# Visual studio 19 throws error on add reference

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Visual studio 19 throws error “Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component” on adding reference in web forms project.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution

Set the path to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\

And run : gacutil -i Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.11.0.dll

If you get following status ,then you are done :

Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Assembly successfully added to the cache